# Reverse the nodes in linked list with stack .why the new linked list become so large?

Tags: python, linked-list, stack

I want to reverse nodes in a linked list with stack.so I first create a linked list:

```
head = ListNode(0)
temp = head
temp.next = ListNode(1)
temp = temp.next
temp.next = ListNode(2)
```

then I use stack to store the list nodes, then pop them to a new linked list *new_tail* to reverse the given linked list.

```
dummy_node = ListNode(0)
cur = head
new_tail = dummy_node
while cur:
    i = 0
    tmp_sk = [] # use the stack to store the elements of linked list
    tmp_tail = cur 
    while i < 3:        
        if cur:
            tmp_sk.append(cur)
            cur = cur.next
            i +=1
        else:
            new_tail.next = tmp_tail
            break
    while tmp_sk:
        new_tail.next = tmp_sk.pop()
        new_tail = new_tail.next
```

but something strange happened. when I try to print the new linked list, the list is very large.

```
count = 0
new = dummy_node
while new:
    count+=1
    print(new.val)
    new = new.next
```

the count can be a large number and the print can't stop util I intervene.
I couldn't find where the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

- The main issue is that the last node that is appended in the `while tmp_sk` loop, will still have a `next` reference that is not reset. So when the `while tmp_sk` has finished, you have a linked list whose last node is `new_tail`, but that node is not *really* a tail: it has a `next` reference that never got updated, and refers to the node that was originally the second node, and is now the one-but-last node. And so there is a cycle now. The solution is to perform `new_tail.next = None` right after that loop.
- The inner loop should not have `i < 3` as condition. This will only work when your list has three nodes. You should make this generic, and test for `cur` instead. This also means that the `else` block in that loop will never be executed. It should just be omitted.
- The outer loop `while cur:` serves no purpose. Once that loop has made one iteration, it will always exit. It wouldn't make sense if it would make a second iteration and restart with a new stack, etc. So remove that loop and just keep its body.
- The part where you print the list, also prints the value of the dummy node. I don't suppose that is the purpose; so skip that first node.
- Not a problem, but you should divide your code into functions, where each function is responsible for one task: create the list, reverse the list, print the list.

Here is the correction and clean up of your code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

def createList(values):
    # initialise list (generic - from a list of values)
    node = dummy = ListNode(None)
    for val in values:
        node.next = ListNode(val)
        node = node.next
    return dummy.next

def reverseList(head):
    cur = head
    tmp_sk = [] # use the stack to store the elements of linked list
    while cur:
        tmp_sk.append(cur)
        cur = cur.next

    dummy_node = ListNode(None)
    new_tail = dummy_node
    while tmp_sk:
        new_tail.next = tmp_sk.pop()
        new_tail = new_tail.next
    new_tail.next = None # this was missing!
    return dummy_node.next  # return the new head

def printList(head):
    cur = head
    while cur:
        print(cur.val)
        cur = cur.next

# main program
head = createList([0, 1, 2])
head = reverseList(head)
printList(head)
```

Comment: thank you so much~ your answer is greatly appreciated. but I still have some confuse about the main issue. as you say, the next reference never got update. In your code, the createList function also use node = node.next.  So the function will create a linked list with a none referenced tail? why the create function won't have the same problem? Are there something special about the stack? thank you again~

Comment: The `createList` function doesn't have the same problem because the constructor will set the `next` attribute to `None`. So when we do `node.next = ListNode(val)` then that new node will have `next` set to `None` already. This is not the case when reversing the list, as there the constructor is not used, and nodes just keep their `next` attribute as it was unless there is code that updates it.